# Why was Steve Trevor not Steve Trevor, and how did he become Steve Trevor?

Tags: character, dc-extended-universe, wonder-woman-84

In the new [*Wonder Woman 84* (2020)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7126948/), Diana Prince makes a wish to see Steve Trevor, her lost love.  In the next scene, a stranger approaches her and says something only Steve Trevor would know.  In a subsequent scene, you see Chris Pine staring into a mirror at the stranger who approached Diana, and they are one and the same person.  Yet Diana sees him as Steve, and he knows what Steve knows.

How was this possible?  How was Steve Trevor someone else, and how did her wish have something to do with it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's unclear how the wish granting system works in the movie, but whatever you wish for somehow manifests but  not exactly the ways you might have imagined for.

For example,

Barbara wishes to be strong like Diana so she gets strength like Diana but not the other qualities.

Emir wishes for his inheritance to be recognized, so a tall wall comes up.

How do you explain all that ? We can say it's element of magic which is unexplained.

Similarly Diana wishes for Steve to come back, well maybe if she had specifically asked for Steve in his body the story would had been different. But she only asked for Steve, so my guess is the spell working behind the wish-system brought back Steve's set of memories from some cosmic database of memory.

As Steve was dead years ago bringing his body might be difficult for spell-system unless it was preserved in some ice ( like Captain America ).

Steve's memory *possessed* the body of a random stranger. But Diana chooses to see only Steve in that body and hence the face of Chris Pine.

Comment: I don't see any evidence that Diana sees the face of Steve. We do, through the translation power of the lens and because they wanted the original actor, but the mirror shows that he looks like his host in-universe, and Diana clearly knows what the host looks like (or she wouldn't have recognised him at the end). Rather, she "looks past" the different appearance throughout the movie (it's what's inside that counts!), which would be sweet if not for the whole _completely inconsensual body theft and rape_ element. Imagine if Superman had gone through this with a reincarnated Lois. Eesh.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: You are quite right. That's why I said that _Diana chooses to see Steve._ and not _Diana sees Steve._

Comment: I still think he should've come back as a charred walking corpse, but then they would've had to up the rating and lose the youth audience, and it would've made the romance scenes *really* tough to watch...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Entertaining though 

Answer (score 4):

> How was this possible?

### Magic

How was Steve Trevor someone else?

The original Steve Trevor is deceased and his body, thus, no longer available.

> did her wish have something to do with it?

### Yes

When Diana wished Steve would come back his "spirit" is transferred into a new body of a currently living person.

When the "new" Steve is able to convince Diana that it is really him, she sees him *as* Steve from then on.

Of course, out-of-universe, this is an excuse to include the "original" Steve and have him be amazed at the way the world has advanced since he's been gone. The "return" of Steve is also crucial to Diana's choice to renounce her wish despite it meaning that she will lose Steve forever.

Comment: Per my comment on Rahul's answer, I saw no evidence that Diana sees Steve's face at any point during the movie, except in photographs.

Comment: _"The "return" of Steve is also crucial to Diana's choice to renounce her wish despite it meaning that she will lose Steve forever."_ Shame it wasn't because she realised it was wrong to will her boyfriend to steal someone else's body without sparing even a second thought for the fate of its owner, never mind engaging in sexual relations with that stolen body.